# How to force unencoded url to show in users browser?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm using ASP.NET and am looking to redirect users to a page that includes an easily human readable URL. Every method I've tried takes in the URL and encodes it.

Since none of the parameters are taken in to the page or processed in any way, I don't believe there's any security concerns with turning the %20 into a space. If there is an IIS rule this would work on, I would be fine to turn off encoding on this one page, but I can't turn it off for the whole page as this is a special use case.

I've already tried having Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer, and I cannot use Literals as putting the query into the page somewhere could allow an XSS vulnerability.

Expected:

example.com/test?message=Hello World

Actual:

example.com/test?message=Hello%20World

Edit For More Clarity:

```
<script>
    console.log(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
    function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
    }
    console.log(window.location.pathname + replaceAll(window.location.search, '%20', ' '));
    window.history.pushState(window.location.search, "Title", window.location.pathname + replaceAll(window.location.search, '%20', ' '));
</script>
```

This will write the current URL to the console, then the URL I'd like to see, but then the pushState does not actually update the URL to one without the encoding - it automatically re-encodes it.

I understand this may be impossible, but if someone could explain why then I will at least be able to stop trying so hard to find a solution.

Comment: spaces are not valid characters for URLs.

Comment: So I understand a user sending in something like: 

GET /test?message=Hello%20World HTTP/1.1

with a space would make it come in as:

GET /test?message=Hello World HTTP/1.1

Which would be invalid to the server, but I am just looking to change the portion the user sees in the browser to remove the %20.

Comment: Do you mean you want to modfiy the url which is show in the user bowser? In my opinion, this is improssible. Since if you remove the %20 in the url, the IIS server will regards the url without space, it may return 404 error, since the IIS server couldn't find the resource which is related with the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Brando Zhang's comment this appears impossible.